# docker auth plugin with docker remote api

Tags: docker

I was reading about docker auth plugin that it can be used to provide access to the containers based on username which can be extracted . Can docker auth plugin work with docker remote api calls. If so how will the username provided in rest calls.

Comment: What have you tried so far? can you provide any code, effort etc.?

Comment: hi was reading about twistlock authz plugin( https://github.com/twistlock/authz ) in which basic policy can be created based on username.and username shall be extracted from the certificates from https call..however what if https is not enabled for docker daemon.how will the username be passed then..